# Ad Consent Android App - How to Clear so can try again

Tags: android, ads

I have programmed the Ad consent for Europeans as per the page:

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent

It seems to be working nicely, but I want to clear my choices so it thinks I have no made a choice yet, so I can retest. **How can this be done?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either uninstall and reinstall the app, or just clear the app data on the device or emulator by going to "Settings -> Apps & Notifications -> Your App -> Storage -> Clear Data"

The Consent SDK information about the user's choice is stored in SharedPreferences, which will be cleared by clearing the data or re-installing the app.

If you are looking to do this programatically, you can reset the consent status to `UNKNOWN` manually by calling

```
ConsentInformation.getInstance(context).setConsentStatus(ConsentStatus.UNKNOWN);
```

which should trigger the consent dialog on the next launch at least (depending on where you call this relative to the dialog launch).

Comment: The ConsentStatus.UNKNOWN piece of code does not work in December 2023. And Quimbo's reset() function should not be used in production code according to google documents. Any idea what we do in 2023?

Comment: @Rewind This solution was really only relevant for the old Consent SDK, which has been deprecated for awhile. In production code if you are using the new UMP SDK you should use `UserMessagingPlatform.showPrivacyOptionsForm(context)` to re-launch the dialog - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68310602/9473786) for an example, or check [the docs](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy). This question was about testing though, in which case using `UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(this).reset()` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's never too late to give an answer, this can help someone else who needs it.

> Key Point: It is important that the user is able to change or revoke
> the consent they have provided at any time.

To revoke the consent and start again, simply call this function where you deem it convenient. [As describe here in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy#reset_consent_state)

```
ConsentInformation consentInformation = ConsentInformation.getInstance(Context);
consentInformation.reset();
```

However, this is not recommended.

> Caution: This method is intended to be used for testing purposes only.
> You shouldn't call reset() in production code.

According to the comments in [this forum](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/F_QHhhE5Qro/m/JaCULPL4BAAJ), the best way would be:

To trigger the revocation of the previous consent in your app, you can implement a method that requests consent again from the users. This method can be integrated into your app's settings section, typically labeled as 'Modify Consent'.

When users access this 'Modify Consent' option, it will invoke the method designed to request consent again. This approach allows users to review and potentially modify their previous consent choices.

Comment: But, their documentation says you should not use the reset() function in production code. And Tyler V's code does not work in December 2023.

Comment: @Rewind From the google admob sdk forum. They suggest this way too. 
[Doubts about Reset consent state](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/F_QHhhE5Qro/m/JaCULPL4BAAJ) Of course, it may not be the best way. I will update my answer.