# How to do the Admob gdpr consent changes with flutter?

Tags: flutter, admob, gdprconsentform

i read all of the documentation but i absolutely don't understand, what i have to do about the Admob GDPR consent changes.

I have some Flutter Apps in the Google Playstore with Ads from Admob (and a few from Mediation from other ad networks).
I already made the GDPR message on Admob.

Now there is a Flutter Package called gdpr_dialog. (I would be open to other packages or solutions.)
If I use the gdpr_dialog package, is it enough to just call

`GdprDialog.instance.showDialog();`

at every start of the app and build a button in the settings where a user can change their consent, and just call it again on the press of the button?

Or do i have to do more? I don't understand what to do about the "Consent Management Platform that integrates with the TCF" stuff that they mention. What does that mean for me?

And what happens if the user does not consent?

I only found one helpful video tutorial online that made two whole classes for it and made the app start with a 10 second loading indicator everytime, which i didn't like. The gdpr_dialog package is very quick. Also i am still not sure if it is enough to just display the message. Dont i have to send the users decision to google somehow or save it somewhere?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

> Now there is a Flutter Package called gdpr_dialog. (I would be open to other packages or solutions.) If I use the gdpr_dialog package, is it enough to just call

Now you can implement UMP Consent with package **google_mobile_ads** , check this link [Implement UMP Consent Flutter](https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/eu-consent)

> at every start of the app and build a button in the settings where a user can change their consent, and just call it again on the press of the button?

You should only open it once when the app opens for the first time. When the use click **Consent** or **Do not Consent** , it just returns **obtained**. you can just check if the user has selected or not.
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65351543/how-to-implement-ump-sdk-correctly-for-eu-consent/72777100#72777100) provides instructs on how to retrieve value from SharePreferences, but I tested it, and it didn't work.

> And what happens if the user does not consent?

Now when user does not consent, admob returns "No ad to show" when you request an ad.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! The GdprDiaog.instance.showDialog() only shows the dialog if you haven't already seen it. I use the google_mobile_ads package, so that is also already done. So I dont have to check the answer and then write something in my Ad loading methods because google will automatically only send ads when the user consents? (I read something about using AsyncPreferences instead in this case, maybe that works for you?) - I have some placeholder 'ads' that appear if the user has no internet or an adblocker, they dont bring any money but they link to the paywall...