# Is it possible to get cached result of ConsentInformation.getPrivacyOptionsRequirementStatus from previous session?

Tags: android, admob, gdprconsentform, user-messaging-platform

### Background

I'm trying to work with the new SDK from Google to handle the GDPR ad-consent rules, and found some useful websites I've checked out, to handle not just a normal flow, but also query about things that don't exist in the SDK and handle some issues there as well :

- https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy
- https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy/gdpr
- https://github.com/bocops/UMP-workarounds
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68310602/878126
- https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/GDPR-Transparency-and-Consent-Framework/tree/master

### The problem

The normal flow works fine. I query the current state (using `requestConsentInfoUpdate`), and if needed I show the UI to the user (using `loadAndShowConsentFormIfRequired`), and also offer a setting to reach there if that's also needed (using `getPrivacyOptionsRequirementStatus` and `UserMessagingPlatform.showPrivacyOptionsForm`).

Thing is, it sometimes takes some time for querying the current state (can take up to 3 seconds in my case), so I wanted to find how to use what's already cached instead.

### What I've found

In order to reduce the time for query, I've found that the results are already saved, so instead of using `ConsentInformation.canRequestAds` I've found that I can reach the sharedPreferences as shown [**here**](https://github.com/bocops/UMP-workarounds/blob/main/detect_insufficient_consent/android/kotlin/detect_insufficient_consent.kt), and that before everything, to make sure the cached data isn't expired, I tried to call what's shown [**here**](https://github.com/bocops/UMP-workarounds/blob/main/detect_outdated_consent/android/kotlin/detect_outdated_consent.kt). These are all workarounds, so I requested to have something more official, [**here**](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/NOouZpbjuu8).

Only one thing left to avoid query using `requestConsentInfoUpdate` when all is cached already: `getPrivacyOptionsRequirementStatus` .

This function tells if I should offer the user to reach the UI of the ad-consent via the settings of the app.

The docs for it ([**here**](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy/api/reference/com/google/android/ump/ConsentInformation.html#getPrivacyOptionsRequirementStatus())) actually say that I can already use it right away, getting the last session's result by default if it exists:

> Returns
> ...UNKNOWN until requestConsentInfoUpdate(...) is called, and defaults to the previous session's value until requestConsentInfoUpdate(...) completes successfully and ...OnConsentInfoUpdateSuccessListener is called.

Sadly, when trying it out, it doesn't fulfil what the documentation says, so I've reported about this issue [**here**](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/CUL9BnJ0YU4).

### The question

Is this saved somewhere? Can I fetch the cached boolean value for it? If so, how?